# http server implentation, the page does not show properly

Tags: java, http, reactor

well, as i am doing a small project of coding an http server. the code is at

http://code.google.com/p/reactor/

the current puzzle is when asked to parse a page with java script and css. As an http server it just sends a page (copied from another website) and it parsed inproperly. when a simple html page is been parse , by my firefox, it shows ok, however when parsing a more complex page(css+javascript) the page is all wired like this :

> ראשי  חדשות
>   if(getCookie('pais999')==null){varisToplayerDouble="True";isToplayerDouble=(isToplayerDouble=="True")?true:falsevarToplayerCookieName='pais999';varTopLayerCookieExpiredDays=1;varToplayerLink='http://xads.zedo.com/ads2/c?a=239671;g=0;c=455000000;i=0;x=7168;n=455;s=0;k=http://www.pais.co.il/Pais/Games/Lotto/';varToplayerImpression='http://l4.zedo.com/log/p.gif?a=239671;c=455000000;x=7168;n=455;e=i;i=0;s=0;z='+Math.random();varToplayerBigPath='pais/January2007/98one_toplayer.swf';varToplayerSmallPath='pais/January2007/98one_reminder.swf';varToplayerBigWidth=1005;varToplayerBigHeight=500;varToplayerSmallWidth=100;varToplayerSmallHeight=100;varToplayerBigLeft=(0==0)?resWidth/2-ToplayerBigWidth/2:resWidth/2-ToplayerBigWidth/2+0varToplayerBigTop=0;varToplayerSmallLeft=resWidth-ToplayerSmallWidth-0;varToplayerSmallTop=0;varSecondsToChangeBigToSmall=15;}elseif(getCookie('NF999')==null){varisToplayerDouble="True";isToplayerDouble=(isToplayerDouble=="True")?true:falsevarToplayerCookieName='NF999';varTopLayerCookieExpiredDays=1;varToplayerLink='http://xads.zedo.com/ads2/c?a=238663;g=0;c=455000000;i=0;x=7168;n=455;s=0;k=http://www.new-pharm.co.il/SkiGame/?ToolID=OLJD8O';varToplayerImpression='http://l4.zedo.com/log/p.gif?a=238663;c=455000000;x=7168;n=455;e=i;i=0;s=0;z='+Math.random();varToplayerBigPath='NewFarm/Ski/995ONE_TopLayer_550x360.swf';varToplayerSmallPath='NewFarm/Ski/995ONE_Reminder_100x100.swf';varToplayerBigWidth=550;varToplayerBigHeight=360;varToplayerSmallWidth=100;varToplayerSmallHeight=100;varToplayerBigLeft=(0==0)?resWidth/2-ToplayerBigWidth/2:resWidth/2-ToplayerBigWidth/2+0varToplayerBigTop=0;varToplayerSmallLeft=resWidth-ToplayerSmallWidth-0;varToplayerSmallTop=0;varSecondsToChangeBigToSmall=15;}elseif(1==0){}$("divToplayerBig").style.width=ToplayerBigWidth;$("divToplayerBig").style.height=ToplayerBigHeight;$("divToplayerBig").style.left=resWidth/2-ToplayerBigWidth/2;$("divToplayerSmall").style.width=ToplayerSmallWidth;$("divToplayerSmall").style.height=ToplayerSmallHeight;$("divToplayerSmall").style.right=ToplayerSmallWidthvartopOff=0;if(ToplayerBigTop>0)topOff=resHeight-ToplayerBigHeight+ToplayerBigTop;varisMain=false;#divToplayerBig{position:absolute;right:20px;bottom:1px;}body>div#divToplayerBig{position:fixed;}#divToplayerSmall{position:absolute;right:20px;bottom:10px;}body>div#divToplayerSmall{position:fixed;}ראשי|תוצאותLIVE|הימוריספורט|ONEבסלולרי|ONETV
>   |גליצ'ים|BigONE|טוטוווינר|  CrazyONE |

where the source code of the html is :

> ONE:פאר:לאהייתימוכנהלראותאותהמחייכת ראשי  חדשות if(getCookie('pais999')==null){varisToplayerDouble="True";isToplayerDouble=(isToplayerDouble=="True")?true:falsevarToplayerCookieName='pais999';varTopLayerCookieExpiredDays=1;varToplayerLink='http://xads.zedo.com/ads2/c?a=239671;g=0;c=455000000;i=0;x=7168;n=455;s=0;k=http://www.pais.co.il/Pais/Games/Lotto/';varToplayerImpression='http://l4.zedo.com/log/p.gif?a=239671;c=455000000;x=7168;n=455;e=i;i=0;s=0;z='+Math.random();varToplayerBigPath='pais/January2007/98one_toplayer.swf';varToplayerSmallPath='pais/January2007/98one_reminder.swf';varToplayerBigWidth=1005;varToplayerBigHeight=500;varToplayerSmallWidth=100;varToplayerSmallHeight=100;varToplayerBigLeft=(0==0)?resWidth/2-ToplayerBigWidth/2:resWidth/2-ToplayerBigWidth/2+0varToplayerBigTop=0;varToplayerSmallLeft=resWidth-ToplayerSmallWidth-0;varToplayerSmallTop=0;varSecondsToChangeBigToSmall=15;}elseif(getCookie('NF999')==null){varisToplayerDouble="True";isToplayerDouble=(isToplayerDouble=="True")?true:falsevarToplayerCookieName='NF999';varTopLayerCookieExpiredDays=1;varToplayerLink='http://xads.zedo.com/ads2/c?a=238663;g=0;c=455000000;i=0;x=7168;n=455;s=0;k=http://www.new-pharm.co.il/SkiGame/?ToolID=OLJD8O';varToplayerImpression='http://l4.zedo.com/log/p.gif?a=238663;c=455000000;x=7168;n=455;e=i;i=0;s=0;z='+Math.random();varToplayerBigPath='NewFarm/Ski/995ONE_TopLayer_550x360.swf';varToplayerSmallPath='NewFarm/Ski/995ONE_Reminder_100x100.swf';varToplayerBigWidth=550;varToplayerBigHeight=360;varToplayerSmallWidth=100;varToplayerSmallHeight=100;varToplayerBigLeft=(0==0)?resWidth/2-ToplayerBigWidth/2:resWidth/2-ToplayerBigWidth/2+0varToplayerBigTop=0;varToplayerSmallLeft=resWidth-ToplayerSmallWidth-0;varToplayerSmallTop=0;varSecondsToChangeBigToSmall=15;}elseif(1==0){}$("divToplayerBig").style.width=ToplayerBigWidth;$("divToplayerBig").style.height=ToplayerBigHeight;$("divToplayerBig").style.left=resWidth/2-ToplayerBigWidth/2;$("divToplayerSmall").style.width=ToplayerSmallWidth;$("divToplayerSmall").style.height=ToplayerSmallHeight;$("divToplayerSmall").style.right=ToplayerSmallWidthvartopOff=0;if(ToplayerBigTop>0)topOff=resHeight-ToplayerBigHeight+ToplayerBigTop;varisMain=false;#divToplayerBig{position:absolute;right:20px;bottom:1px;}body>div#divToplayerBig{position:fixed;}div#divToplayerBig{right:auto;bottom:auto;left:expression((-20-divToplayerBig.offsetWidth+(document.documentElement.clientWidth?document.documentElement.clientWidth:document.body.clientWidth)+(ignoreMe2=document.documentElement.scrollLeft?document.documentElement.scrollLeft:document.body.scrollLeft))+'px');top:expression((0-divToplayerBig.offsetHeight-topOff+(document.documentElement.clientHeight?document.documentElement.clientHeight:document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe=document.documentElement.scrollTop?document.documentElement.scrollTop:document.body.scrollTop))+'px');}#divToplayerSmall{position:absolute;right:20px;bottom:10px;}body>div#divToplayerSmall{position:fixed;}div#divToplayerSmall{right:auto;bottom:auto;left:expression((-20-divToplayerSmall.offsetWidth+(document.documentElement.clientWidth?document.documentElement.clientWidth:document.body.clientWidth)+(ignoreMe2=document.documentElement.scrollLeft?document.documentElement.scrollLeft:document.body.scrollLeft))+'px');top:expression((0-divToplayerSmall.offsetHeight+(document.documentElement.clientHeight?document.documentElement.clientHeight:document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe=document.documentElement.scrollTop?document.documentElement.scrollTop:document.body.scrollTop))+'px');}varisTopTrans=(ToplayerBigPath.indexOf("transparent")>-1)?false:true;varisRemTrans=(ToplayerSmallPath.indexOf("transparent")>-1)?false:true;vartop1session=3;vartop2session=5;InitToplayer(isTopTrans,isRemTrans);window.onload=StartToplayer;ראשי|תוצאותLIVE|הימוריספורט|ONEבסלולרי|ONETV |גליצ'ים|BigONE|טוטוווינר|  CrazyONE |
> כותרותאחרונותצפובמייקללואיסמנצחבתחרותההטבעותבגמרהתיכונים
> 19/01/07  19:30
> אליכהןלשחקניולקראתבני-יהודה:תיראומהאסוליןעשהלמכביחיפה
> 19/01/07  18:43
> ליגתהעלבכדורסל:המשחקיםחוזריםליוםראשון
> 19/01/07  17:41
> דעה:שחרפארכבריכולהלהתמודדעםשחקניותצמרת
> 19/01/07  16:49
> ארצית:הפועלר"גניצחהאתהשקמה/רמתחן1:2,גםראשל"צניצחה
> 19/01/07  16:45
> יובנטוסמעוניינתבכריסטוףמצלדר,שדורש2.5מיליוןדולרלעונה
> 19/01/07  16:37
> ליגתהעל:בית"רירושליםתתארחמחרב-19:30אצלמכביהרצליה
> 19/01/07  14:32
> מכביפ"תתארחמחרב-18:30אתהפועלכפ"סבאורווה,ללאג'ובניני
> 19/01/07  14:45
> הגרלהקלהלהפועלירושליםבשמיניתהיול"ב:ונטספילסהלטבית
> 19/01/07  14:37
> ליגהלאומית:הפועלירושליםואחינצרתנפרדובתיקו0:0
> 19/01/07  13:46
> varswfPeleSmall=newSWFObject("http://images.one.co.il/images/PeleEmulator/emulator_pelephone_01a.swf","peleSmall",160,470,"6","#FFFFFF");swfPeleSmall.addParam("quality","high");swfPeleSmall.addParam("wmode","transparent");swfPeleSmall.write("divPeleSmall");varswfPeleBig=newSWFObject("http://images.one.co.il/images/PeleEmulator/emulator_pelephone_02d.swf","peleBig",400,470,"6","#FFFFFF");swfPeleBig.addParam("quality","high");swfPeleBig.addParam("wmode","transparent");swfPeleBig.write("divWithBig");
> פאר:לאהייתימוכנהלראותאותהמחייכת
> שחרפארסיפרהל-ONEמהעברבמוחהברגעיםשבהםכמעטהפסידהלטטיאנהגולובין.הישראלית,שניצחהלבסוף1:2,ידעהלמילהודות:"הקהלהיהנפלא"
> DisplayFlash("W_S_round_border_pic.swf","156","201","1","style=position:absolute");שחרפארחוזרתמהקברמוליריבתה(רויטרס)
> מאתשיאלון                          19/01/20077:26
> שחרפאררשמההבוקר(שישי)אתאחדההישגיםהגדוליםשלהכשגברה6:3,5:7ו-5:7עלטטיאנהגולוביןהצרפתייה,המדורגת23בעולם.
> המשחק,שהיהאמורלהיערךלפנותבוקרבאוסטרליה,נדחהעקבהגשםופארשהפסידהבגללתנאימזגהאווירבעבר,השלימהקאמבקשכולואופי.
> אחרישהפסידהאתהמערכההראשונה,היהנראהשפארבדרךהבטוחההחוצה.לפתעפארהתעוררהוהצליחהלהשוותל-1:1אתהמערכות.בשעההאחרונההיאניצלהפעמייםממאצ'פוינטכשנאבקהנואשותמולהצרפתייה.בסוףזההשתלםלה.
> פארהבטיחהאתההעפלהלשלבשמיניתהגמר(16הגדולות),שםתפגושבשבתבלילהאתסבטלנהקוזנצובההמדורגת3בטורניר,שגברההבוקרעלמריהקרילנקו.
> פאראמרהל-

(only part of of the page presentation in firefox and page source html)

why is it happening? what is midding in the http response?

```
StringBuffer tResponse = new StringBuffer();
        tResponse.append("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");
    tResponse.append("Date: "+new Date().toString() +'\n');
    tResponse.append("server: http-reactor/0.1-dev\n");
    tResponse.append("last-Modified:"+ d.toString() +'\n');
    tResponse.append("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1255\n");
    tResponse.append("Accept-Language: he; q=1.0, en; q=0.5:);
    tResponse.append("Content-Length: "+tFileContent.length()+'\n');
    tResponse.append('\n');
    tResponse.append(tFileContent);

    public StringBuffer FetchData(String FileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
    StringBuffer tFileContent = new StringBuffer();
    if (FileName.contains("../"))
        throw new SecurityException();
    if (FileName.equals("/"))
        FileName = "\\index.html";
    FileName.replace('/', '\\');
    File f = new File(_root + FileName);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
    while(scanner.hasNext())
        tFileContent.append(scanner.next());
    return generateResponse(tFileContent,f.lastModified());
}

private StringBuffer generateResponse(StringBuffer tFileContent, long l) {
    StringBuffer tResponse = new StringBuffer();
    Date d = new Date(l);
    tResponse.append("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");
    tResponse.append("Date: "+new Date().toString() +'\n');
    tResponse.append("server: http-reactor/0.1-dev\n");
    tResponse.append("last-Modified:"+ d.toString() +'\n');
    tResponse.append("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1255\n");
    tResponse.append("Accept-Language: he; q=1.0, en; q=0.5:);
    tResponse.append("Content-Length: "+tFileContent.length()+'\n');
    tResponse.append('\n');
    tResponse.append(tFileContent);
    return tResponse;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using "quote" formatting instead of "code" formatting, which is not so great for your example,s but then again, your examples are way too big. Try finding a minimal case that exhibits the problem you are experiencing. You say you think this is caused by mixing JS and CSS in your HTML, so make a *short* HTML page that has a line or so of each. Also, there's a good chance that your problem relates to how `tFileContent` is set, yet you haven't shown us any of the code that sets it or even what its type is.

Comment: There is a link to the source control

Answer (score 1):

Why should you scan the file first. Just open an input stream in the correct encoding (windows-1255 in your example) and stream down the content.

BTW. If you're writing a HTTP server, you should be aware that you do not deal with strings. So StringBuffer is not a good choice anyway

Comment: What do you mean by alternate stream handler. I assume you want to stream down the file content. Open a FileInputStream and copy every single byte to the OutputStream

Answer (score 1):

Try setting response content type to UTF-8 in jsp page and meta content tags would help.

response.setContentType('utf-8');

tResponse.append("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n");

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to set the content-type header correctly? Also, StringBuffer would give you trouble when you load images.